# Reclaiming memory from threads

Tags: python, multithreading, memory, multiprocessing

I have a simple program which spawns a few threads, gets results and saves it. It looks like the memory used by the program just increases all the time and does not get claimed back. How can I force the threads to return the memory they've claimed?

Here's a simplified example:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
from time import sleep


def return_data(arg):
    # return 100MB of data for testing.
    return 'x' * int(1e8)


def multi_process():
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    processes = pool.imap(return_data, xrange(5))
    for data in processes:
        print('got data')
        del data
    print('data processed')
    sleep(15)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    pool.terminate()
    del processes
    print('everything deleted')
    sleep(15)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    multi_process()
```

Even after the threads (not processes because I'm using multiprocessing.dummy package) are terminated the memory seems to be not reclaimed as seen by htop or when profiled by memory_profiler.